# How to parse table from the links using Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse table from the links but can't get it.
I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1200x1900")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
url = "http://www.stats.gov.cn/was5/web/search?channelid=288041&andsen=流通领域重要生产资料市场价格变动情况"
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)

driver.close()


for href in soup.find_all(class_='searchresulttitle'):
    #print(href)
    links = href.attrs['href']
    print(links)
```

With this, I can get links only but from that How I get a table from each link and store in excel file using Python.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until those links generated:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get(url)
links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, searchresulttitle)))
refs = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
```

Comment: Sir i got the links :
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181024_1629464.html
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181024_1629464.html
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181015_1627579.html
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181015_1627579.html
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181009_1626612.html
http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181009_1626612.html  Like that, So How can I get Table from It

Comment: You can now iterate through links and get table on each page: `for ref in refs: driver.get(ref); print(driver.find_element_by_class_name('MsoNormalTable').text)`

Comment: What is 'MsoNormalTable'

Comment: By your way error is: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64)

Comment: @royal , that's because you closed the WebDriver session with `driver.close()` . Don't do this :) `MsoNormalTable` is the class name of `table` on each page

Comment: I close it at end of code and also I remove it but the error is comming contineous\

Comment: @royal , on which line it breaks? Try to update chromedriver version to up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. As the [Web App](http://www.stats.gov.cn/was5/web/search?channelid=288041&andsen=%E6%B5%81%E9%80%9A%E9%A2%86%E5%9F%9F%E9%87%8D%E8%A6%81%E7%94%9F%E4%BA%A7%E8%B5%84%E6%96%99%E5%B8%82%E5%9C%BA%E4%BB%B7%E6%A0%BC%E5%8F%98%E5%8A%A8%E6%83%85%E5%86%B5) is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elements to be visible* within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and then you can use **BeautifulSoup** to parse and print the *href* attributes as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  my_url = 'http://www.stats.gov.cn/was5/web/search?channelid=288041&andsen=??????????????????'
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe", )
  driver.get(my_url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='searchresulttitle']")))
  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
  driver.quit()
  for href in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"searchresulttitle"}):
      print(href.attrs['href'])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181024_1629464.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181024_1629464.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181015_1627579.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181015_1627579.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181009_1626612.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181009_1626612.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180925_1624525.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180925_1624525.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180914_1622865.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180914_1622865.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180904_1620652.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180904_1620652.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180824_1618797.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180824_1618797.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180814_1615716.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180814_1615716.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180806_1614209.html
  http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180806_1614209.html
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing with without selenium. It seems to make it easier for me. The problem is that javascript is running but it's weird that the script data is printed in the html. I used regex to pull it out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import time

urls = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'http://www.stats.gov.cn/was5/web/search?channelid=288041&andsen=%E6%B5%81%E9%80%9A%E9%A2%86%E5%9F%9F%E9%87%8D%E8%A6%81%E7%94%9F%E4%BA%A7%E8%B5%84%E6%96%99%E5%B8%82%E5%9C%BA%E4%BB%B7%E6%A0%BC%E5%8F%98%E5%8A%A8%E6%83%85%E5%86%B5'

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

centerColumn = soup.findAll('span', class_='cont_tit')

for eachSpan in centerColumn:
    match = re.findall('http://www.stats.gov.cn/.+.html', str(eachSpan))
    if match != [] and match not in urls:
        urls.append(match)

for each in urls:
    #If you want to scrape the tables on each page. Assuming they are all the same. Just comment out the print statement and uncomment the other stuff.
    print(each)
    #page = requests.get(each, headers=headers)
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    #middleTable = soup.find('table', class_='MsoNormalTable')
    #rows = middleTable.findAll('tr')
    #for eachRow in rows:
        #print(eachRow.text)
    #time.sleep(1)
Output = 
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181024_1629464.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181015_1627579.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201810/t20181009_1626612.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180925_1624525.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180914_1622865.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201809/t20180904_1620652.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180824_1618797.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180814_1615716.html']
['http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201808/t20180806_1614209.html']
```

Comment: You can also put a time.sleep() so to give it some time between pages.